# FIREBASE - ReferenceError: Cannot access 'auth' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

i'm in the middle to learn Auth with `Firebase` using `NextJS`, tryin to understand using multiple source (article / youtube) but i'm stuck with this error

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'auth' before initialization`

Honestly i'm still tryin to find `the source` but still stuck

Here's my `firebase.js`

```js
import { firebase, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH,
  projectId: process.env.PID,
  storageBucket: process.env.BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MSID,
  appId: process.env.AID,
  measurementId: process.env.MID,
};
const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = app.auth();
const db = app.firestore();
const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export {
  auth,
  db,
  signInWithGoogle,
  ...
};
```

and this is my `login.js` page

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  auth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithGoogle,
} from "../../firebase/index";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
      // maybe trigger a loading screen
      return;
    }
    if (user) {
      alert("GET USER");
      console.log(user);
    }
  }, [user, loading]);
  return (
  ...
```

I'm using

```
"firebase": "^9.6.1",
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.1",
```

am i doing something wrong? or am i missing something? please help:(

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must import `getAuth()` from Firebase Auth SDK and then initialize it as shown below:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export {
  auth,
  db,
};
```

You don't need to check if Firebase has already been initialized when using Modular SDK.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i really appriciate it,  just copied all of your code above, but i still got the same error

Comment: @HaksatryaBhaswara try restarting your dev server once.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i just restart my dev server, even restart my laptop, and still doesnt work, but i really appriciate your help! thanks a lot.

Comment: having same issue, followed fire base docs, looks like th above code snippet. but stil having the "Another Firebase SDK was initialized and is trying to use Auth before Auth is initialized" error

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using the legacy version of firebase I recommend you to use newer versions (9.9.2 atm).
About your problem ; it seems like you need to call getAuth() or initializeAuth() functions before try to get instance of auth.